# collision of two bodies

Tags: linear-algebra, applications

Two cars A and B, each 5 m in length, travel with constant velocity 20 m/s along a straight level road.
The front of car A is 15 m directly behind the rear of car B.
Immediately on reaching a point P each car decelerates at 4 m/s/s.
Find the time at which collision occurs? Please explain

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  let $a(t)$ be the position of the front of car A and $b(t)$ be the position of the rear of car B in meters right of P-these are the points that will collide.  Let $t=0$ be when the front of car B reaches P.  What are $a(0)$ and $b(0)$?  As A has not reached P, for a while more you have $a(t)=a(0)+5t$  What is the equation for $b(t)$-it starts decelerating at $t=0$?

Comment: http://www.thephysicsteacher.ie/Exam%20Material/AppliedMaths/Scans/1.%20Linear%20Acceleration/1989.pdf  this link shows the right answer but one thing i dont understand is in sA=sB-5. where did the -5 come from

Comment: The -5 comes because sA and sB measure the positions of the front of the two car.  As car B is 5m long and impact happens when the front of A meets the back of B, you need to subtract $5$.  I took account of that in my definition of $b(t)$